# Append last date of current month to a file name in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have afile name e.g. ABC.pdf. I wish to add the last day of the current month.

e.g.ABC_20221031.pdf (current month is Oct, last day of current month is 31).

In xx.bat file.

Answer (score 0):

30 days hath September, April, June and November. This month is 11 so last day is 30, the best tool is **Dave Benham**'s DosTips BATch file

[jTimestamp.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7523) `/C "OM=0,UD=-1" /F "filename{yyyy}{mm}{dd}"`

will return

filename20221130

for end of last month its `"OM=-1,UD=-1"` =`"abc20221031.pdf"`

However, you will need to enwrap that "filename" variable in your own call since that is the perfect solution for this task.
say

```
>for %a in (*.pdf) do @"cmd /r "jTimestamp.bat /C "OM=0,UD=-1" /F "ren "%a" "%~na{yyyy}{mm}{dd}.pdf""">>ren2EOM.cmd
```

should work for all normal cases except [Feb 30th or 31st](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_non-standard_dates#February_30)

[image]